# Unordered Lists are stacking instead of appearing next to each other

Tags: html, styles

I am having trouble getting my two unordered lists next to each other on my webpage. Instead they are stacking on each other. Does anyone know how I can get them to appear next to each other side by side?[Full code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mA8yk.jpg)
I'm thinking I will have to use a style that I am just not aware of yet...
Thank you

Comment: Wrap the two lists in a `div` tag and add `display: flex flex-direction: row` to that `div`. 
The `float` attribute is causing your lists to stack. If you want ot use float you can read up on it hear https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/float

Comment: Please don't post the code as screenshot, write it!

Answer (score 0):

Please learn how to use `clear` with `float` property.

https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_float_clear.asp